# UTF-8 без BOM не понимает русский язык

Tags: php, utf-8

Страница должна быть в utf-8, но когда она в utf-8 не срабатывает php скрипт в начале страницы ,а когда в utf-8 без bom то скрипт срабатывает но русский язык нет,что делать подскажите ?
    <?php
    session_start();

```
include ("bd.php");
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id =$_GET['id']; } 
else
{ exit("121!");} 
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
exit("<p>ифв URL</p>");
}

if (!empty($_SESSION['email']) and !empty($_SESSION['password']))
{
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'",$db); 
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2); 
if (empty($myrow2['id']))
   {
    exit("bad id!");
   }
}
else {
exit("122"); }
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'",$db); 
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($myrow['email'])) { exit("123");}

?>
```

Comment: Каким редактором пользуетесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .htaccess допишите строку:

```
addDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Данный эффект проявляется в зависимости от редактора. Есть несколько вариантов решения:

1. Создать новый файл с нужной кодировкой, и вставить нужный код.
2. Преобразовать файл в ютф-8, удалить самый первый невидимый символ, для этого необходимо поставить курсор в начало строки и нажать "delete"
3. Воспользоваться другим редактором.